# Utilizing an almost dead battery of an old laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

One of my relatives have a laptop whose battery has gone almost dead. They have not bought the  battery but they still want to use the laptop. I just did some research and found that if the battery is 100% charged you can remove the laptops battery safely while the AC supply is there. Now my question is, how can one utilize a dead battery of a laptop? The laptop powers on sometimes for a few minutes. If the battery is removed in this time period, will the laptop be still turned on?

Please do not suggest me to ask them to buy a battery as the laptop is a P4 and I don't think they want to buy a battery for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of laptop? many laptops work rather happily with no battery at all

Comment: Its a P4 by Fujitsu. I don't know other specs. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the battery is almost dead, and they don't want to spend anything on this by getting a new battery, then that seems to answer the question. Just keep the battery connected in the laptop and always use the AC adapter. The semi-dead battery will act like a short term power buffer for those situations when they temporarily unplug the power cord (either intentionally to move  locations, or accidently bump it out). A dying battery typically has one bad cell will charge to 100% and then completely discharge within minutes of using load.